# How to simplify the following combination sum?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Does any one know how to get a compact solution to the following formula?

$$\binom{n}{1} \cdot n + \binom{n}{2} \cdot (n - 1) + ... + \binom{n}{n} \cdot 1 = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k} \cdot (n + 1 - k)}$$

The answer may be something related to $2^n$, but I currently have no clues on how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: Btw, this should be the rough runtime of database query optimization with n operators in total, using the dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: I currently have no clues on how to proceed. Just want to see if there is a way to get a compact answer. For example, something related to $2^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (n+1-k)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} (n+1) - \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} - n \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=(n+1)(2^n-1) - n 2^{n-1}\\
&= (n+2) 2^{n-1}-n -1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Start with a change of index $j=n-k$. The sum we’re looking for rewrites as

$$S=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1){n\choose n-j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1){n\choose j}$$

Then consider

$$x(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}x^{j+1}$$

Derive that once to get

$$(1+x)^n+nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1){n\choose j}x^j$$

Evaluating at $x=1$ we have

$$2^{n-1}(2+n)=S+(n+1){n\choose n}$$
$$S=2^{n-1}(2+n)-(n+1)$$